# How can I filter for records whose sum make up X% of the total in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio, quantile

I have a data set containing clients and two dimensions: `Lifetime` and `Revenue`, e.g.

| Client | Lifetime | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tesla | 7,4 | 280 |
| Amazon | 9,2 | 450 |
| Disney | 2,6 | 130 |
| Otto | 11,8 | 940 |
| BMW | 3,5 | 170 |

I am trying to calculate the average lifetime, but instead of calculating the average over all clients, I only want to include the top clients (regarding revenue) whose sum of revenue  make up 80% of the total revenue.

When doing this manually the process would be quite clear:

- Sort the clients by revenue descending
- Calculate the total revenue and thus what 80% of
  the total is
- Check at which row the running sum of the client's revenue exceeds that 80% and only include the records up to that point

This is what the resulting table would look like:

| Client | Lifetime | Revenue | Running Sum of Rev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Otto | 11,8 | 940 | 940 |
| Amazon | 9,2 | 450 | 1390 |
| Tesla | 7,4 | 280 | 1670 |
| BMW | 3,5 | 170 | 1840 |
| Disney | 2,6 | 130 | 1970 |

Since the total revenue is 1970, 80% of that would amount to 1576. Therefore I would want to select the top 3 (Otto, Amazon, Tesla) from the set, because their running sum (1670) is just bigger than the 1576.
Then I could calculate the average lifetime of those three clients only.

I have no idea if this is possible in an automated way in Google Data Studio. Filters can only take absolute values and in datasets/blends the order is also not regarded.

**Alternative**:
I would already be quite happy with something like including only the top 80% clients from the list of clients sorted by revenue (i.e. the 80% quantile). This would be the top 4 in the example (0.8 * 5 = 4), instead of the top 3 as of the original question, but that seems equally impossible.

[Data Set (Google Sheets)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wun81qFmA0iXMKknAAZjUshsV9Grb5sn7DnNY0eyxWY/edit?usp=sharing)

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/804a7361-9cf1-4505-875a-4d8aa928a341)